# mysterious gadget That makes whinnying sound. help identifying circuit board plz

Tags: identification

I found this little gadget in one of my spare rooms in a bunch of old electronics and cords. I didn't make it and I don't know who could have. I've tried identifying it and nothing.

I put a little power to it and it makes a whinnying sound. I will take pics of it from outside then the board. Someone went to great lengths to close it up used a thick black composite maybe jb weld? I had to shave down and cut into the end in  order to open it.

Comment: https://picasaweb.google.com/m/viewer?dc=gorganic&source=mobileproducts#album/114502850009859486002/5773556572920343105

Comment: This link does not work. Please upload the image using the image upload function in the question editor.

Comment: maybe it's a horse?

Comment: @markrages Beware, there may be Greeks inside...

Comment: This is just guessing with no way to be sure with the amount of information given.

Answer (score 2):

Often, components in power supplies will vibrate causing an audible hum. Sometimes, this is avoided by covering them with a thick epoxy or other potting compound.

If it is a power supply, great care should be taken when opening it.

Comment: https://picasaweb.google.com/m/viewer?dc=gorganic&source=mobileproducts#album/114502850009859486002/5773556572920343105

Comment: @kymberli The picasa links do not work unless the person viewing is signed into picasa - I personally just get a login page.